# sum a col from a grouped tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
datasetmax <- data.frame(pearl = c('new','new','recurrent','recurrent','new'),
                         jam = c(10,20,30,40,50), 
                         dog = c(1,2,3,1,2),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I grouped the dataframe to a summary:

```
datasetmax %>% 
  mutate(temple = ifelse(pearl == 'new', jam * 0.1, jam * 0.2)) %>% 
  group_by(pearl) %>% summarise(plus = sum(temple), weight = sum(jam*dog)/sum(dog))
```

I want the sum of the column weight (the two values), should be 62.5

I tried the following code:

```
datasetmax %>% 
  mutate(temple = ifelse(pearl == 'new', jam * 0.1, jam * 0.2)) %>% 
  group_by(pearl) %>% summarise(plus = sum(temple), weight = sum(jam*dog)/sum(dog)) %>% colSums(plus)
```

But it tells me that column "plus" doesn't exist. Why? Could you please give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: You are mixing the non-standard evaluation of the tidyverse (i.e. just referring to bare variable names) with the base R function `colSums`. But note that `colSums` is an odd choice for summing a single column.

Comment: I would do  %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,sum) ... instead of %>% colSums(..)

Comment: Hello @DarrenTsai, thank you for the answer, works fine.

Comment: Hello @Axeman, thanks for the comments, just a question, is it bad programming to mix up tidy verse with base R?

Comment: Hello @StupidWolf, to work out your idea I tried `summarise_if(is.numeric,sum) %>% pull(plus)` and gave me the value I needed. Thank you.

Comment: It's fine to combine, but the functions don't work the same way. `dplyr` works like `verb(data, variable)` and base often works like `function(data$variable)`. You tried to do the first way, but you needed the second. In this particular case, you can just do `datasetmax %>% mutate(.....) %>% pull(temple) %>% sum()`.

Comment: Great @Axeman, your answer worked fine and helped me in this question and made me understand the dplyr concept. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
datasetmax %>% 
  mutate(temple = ifelse(pearl == 'new', jam * 0.1, jam * 0.2)) %>% 
  group_by(pearl) %>% summarise(plus = sum(temple), weight = sum(jam*dog)/sum(dog)) %>% 
  select(weight) %>% sum()
```

Comment: Thank you @Orlando Sabogal for your time and answer.